# Error: Unable to access jarfile. Can't fix this issue

Tags: java, jar

When I try to execute .jar file like:

```
cd /var/www/html/
java -jar demo.jar
```

It works good. But when I try to execute like:

```
java -jar "/var/www/html/demo.jar"
```

Getting error message:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /var/www/html/demo.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a java problem but more of a file permission problem. What happens when you do "ls -l /var/www/html" ?

Comment: @JosephLarson total 1408
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root 1438075 Jul  7 16:49 demo.jar

Comment: @att13 Might want to run as root then.

Comment: @MingleLi running as root, same problem

Comment: Are you sure you need `"` around your path to jar?

Comment: @talex I tested with and without. same thing

Comment: Fix the file permissions to allow read access.

Comment: @JosephLarson it has 777 permisiion

Comment: --wx-wx-wx is 777 ? I would think you would wish to see -rwxrwxrwx for that.    $ chmod 777 foo
$ ls -l foo
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jpl  staff  0 Jul  7 14:36 foo   $ chmod 333 foo
$ ls -l foo
--wx-wx-wx  1 jpl  staff  0 Jul  7 14:36 foo

Comment: This is might not because of the permission of .jar file but the problem of the folder. Let's try to move your jar to another accessible folder and try to run it.